# How to check scope in DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: dotnetopenauth

In my DotNetOpenAouth client application I obtain an authorization code/token by sending

`AuthorizationEP + "?client_id=" + _appId + "&redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl.ToString()) + "&scope=http://localhost:4314/api/domains" + "&response_type=code"`.

Then, I correctly received an auth token for `http://localhost:4314/api/domains` scope.

But, when I call my Restful api by `http://localhost:4314/api/domains.json` or `http://localhost:4314/api/domains.xml` URL, the specified scope does not fit and my resource server throws an exception in `resourceServer.GetPrincipal`.

How can I check my scope without consider ".json" or ".xml" in url?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Tip: read about how you should [use Uri.AbsoluteUri instead of Uri.ToString()](http://blog.nerdbank.net/2008/04/uriabsoluteuri-and-uritostring-are-not.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved.

I have implemented

```
 internal class ScopeSatisfiedCheck : IScopeSatisfiedCheck
     {
         public bool IsScopeSatisfied(HashSet<string> requiredScope, HashSet<string> grantedScope)
         {
             // Here compare requiredScope with grantedScope by own rules;
         }
     }

....

resourceServer.ScopeSatisfiedCheck = new ScopeSatisfiedCheck();
```

I hope is useful

Carmelo